# logic of adding numbers inside for loop statement

Tags: loops, for-loop, logic, addition, increment

i would like to know the logic behind the following forloop.

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){  
document.write(i+6); // i can't understand whats the logic working here
}
```

the result is: 678910

Actually i was looking for a forloop which is starting from any number and repeating with a condition at certain time. I found the above forloop is doing exact function as i expect. But i can't understand the logic and functional structure happening there. As per my understanding it should not work as the condition mentioend in the parenthesis is "i<5" but i added i in the statement as "i+6" which is greater than 5, so it should get error. But i wonder why it works. And also i am confused on the interrelation between the i of the body of forloop and i inside the parenthesis (). Can anyone explain it in simple theory because i hope understanding this logic is important in further stage of my work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The qucik answer is that you don't assign value i+6 to the variable i.

Try to compare the following different code
**Code CASE 1:**

```js
for(i=0;i<5;i++){  
   document.write(i+6); 
}
```

Result: 678910

**Code CASE 2:**

```js
for(i=0;i<5;i++){  
   i = i + 6;
   document.write(i); // i can't understand whats the logic working her
}
```

Result:6

You can think about what difference between case 1 and case 2.
Case 1 use i + 6
Case 2 use i = i + 6 and it finish the loop early.

Because your code (Code CASE 1) don't assign value to the variable i, so the variable i still satisfy the condition i<5.

In code case 2, you assign value i+6 to the variable i. so i become 6 and exit loop because the condition is i<5.

Comment: Hi Milo Chen, Thank You for your Wonderful Answer and Logical Explanation!. I did'nt expect that i'll get a master description like this. Appreciate your observation and patience to answer my basic question. Your first sentence itself cleared my entire doubt. The developers like you are making the magics. Thank You Very Much !!!